# What is "java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address"?

Tags: java, sockets, exception, tcp, hole-punching

That's it.
I have never seen before. I am trying Tcp Holepunching.

One Client should be both client and server(for other client).

I got this Exception. Is there anyone who know about this problem?

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.temp.TcpSocketClient$4.run(TcpSocketClient.java:563)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Where is the code that should accompany this question?

Answer (score 4):

hey can you check you request is use keep-Alive option? If you are doing a stress test, please try turning it off.

Answer (score 0):

Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the remote host cannot be reached because of an intervening firewall, or if an intermediate router is down.
Read this Documnet

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NoRouteToHostException.html

you can also go through these answers

- [How to avoid a NoRouteToHostException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572215/how-to-avoid-a-noroutetohostexception)
- [NoRouteToHostException on client or server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686445/noroutetohostexception-on-client-or-server)

Comment: I use local environment. thus, so there is no router as well as firewall.
that is answer I am looking for, but this is not solution.

Comment: i have edited my solution.it might be helpful for you .